# Is mysql and sql server provide the stats like ALL_TAB_COLUMNS in oracle.?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

i'm to trying to get the stats from mysql,sql servers.
stats like high value, low value, null count, distinct count. 
Oracle provides these stats in ALL_TAB_COLUMNS. 
Does MySQL,SQL server provide such a table where we can get the stats of all the tables.

Using Oracle

```
select * from all_tab_columns where   owner ="SCHEMA_NAME" and table_name ="TABLENAME";
```

same like does mysql,sql server provides any..?

Comment: you mean like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`?

Comment: I think `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` doesn't provide the stats like min, max, distinct count, null count   @Larnu

Comment: In SQL Server, no there isn't anything that natively gives you the Count (Distinct), max, min values, `NULL` count, etc. You would have to build something yourself.